# How to get variable outside loop?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have this:

```
 countReader = command7.ExecuteReader();
 while (countReader.Read())
 {
    string countName = countReader["count(*)"].ToString();                
 }
```

How to get string countName outside while loop?

Comment: What is `"count(*)"`?  That doesn't look like a valid column name to me.  Are you trying to get the sum of that column?  If not, what *are* you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a variable outside the while loop you should declare it outside like this

```
countReader = command7.ExecuteReader();
string countName = String.Empty;

 while (countReader.Read())
 {
  countName = countReader["count(*)"].ToString();                
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could declare it in the outer scope:

```
countReader = command7.ExecuteReader();
string countName = "";
while (countReader.Read())
{
    countName = countReader["count(*)"].ToString();                
}
// you can use countName here
```

Note that because you are overwriting its value on each iteration, outside the loop you will get its value from the last iteration or an empty string if the loop didn't execute.

Comment: If i may suggest somenthing. One change "" to String.Empty.

Comment: +1 for noting that the countName will be overwritten on each loop, if there's more than one row in the reader.

Answer (score 0):

```
string countName;
countReader = command7.ExecuteReader();
while (countReader.Read())
{
   countName = countReader["count(*)"].ToString();                
}
```

The scope will mean it is still accessible after the loop is exited.